# Select data from 27 tables into a single datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application where l store students grades in 27 tables. From grade 1-9. Each grade has 3 different tables to store grades for first, second and third semester, hence the 27 tables. So my question is how will l go about selecting all grades from a student from grade 1-9 and display using the student ID as a unique identifier for querying.

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from grade1FT_results INNER JOIN grade1ST_results,grade1TT_results,grade2FT_results,grade2ST_results,grade2TT_results,grade3FT_results,grade3ST_results,grade3TT_results,grade4FT_results,grade4ST_results,grade4TT_results,grade5FT_results,grade5ST_results,grade5TT_results,grade6FT_results,grade6ST_results,grade6TT_results,grade7FT_results,grade7ST_results,grade7TT_results,grade8FT_results,grade8ST_results,grade8TT_results,grade9FT_results,grade9ST_results,grade9TT_results ON StudentId=@Id ", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtid.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataTable dtable;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    dtable = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dtable);
    BindingSource dsource = new BindingSource();

    dsource.DataSource = dtable;
    datagrid.DataSource = dsource;
    da.Update(dtable);

    cn.Close();
}
```

I'm getting an error that incorrect syntax: "Incorrect syntax near ','."
on this line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked up INNER JOIN syntax?

Comment: Test your SQL in SSMS before copying it into code

Comment: @Eric its my first time using a JOIN in an sql statement. I have looked but l'm completely new to this.

Comment: Use SSMS to get your query right.  If it's right, then plug it into your code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the problem you have, your SQL is not correct. That is why you are getting that error. Use SQL Server Management Studio to test your SQL rather than doing it from an application; this will save you so much time.

I would HIGHLY recommend making a [VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server to do this. I used LEFT JOINs as it might be possible that a student you want in the results did not attend the school until 10,11, or 12th grade, so I would presume no records. I think this pretty close:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.StudentG1toG9
AS
select * --You need to list out each column here (StudentID only once)
from Student
LEFT JOIN grade1FT_results AS [G1FT] ON [G1FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade1ST_results AS [G1ST] ON [G1ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade1TT_results AS [G1TT] ON [G1TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade2FT_results AS [G2FT] ON [G2FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade2ST_results AS [G2ST] ON [G2ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade2TT_results AS [G2TT] ON [G2TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade3FT_results AS [G3FT] ON [G3FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade3ST_results AS [G3ST] ON [G3ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade3TT_results AS [G3TT] ON [G3TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade4FT_results AS [G4FT] ON [G4FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade4ST_results AS [G4ST] ON [G4ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade4TT_results AS [G4TT] ON [G4TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade5FT_results AS [G5FT] ON [G5FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade5ST_results AS [G5ST] ON [G5ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade5TT_results AS [G5TT] ON [G5TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade6FT_results AS [G6FT] ON [G6FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade6ST_results AS [G6ST] ON [G6ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade6TT_results AS [G6TT] ON [G6TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade7FT_results AS [G7FT] ON [G7FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade7ST_results AS [G7ST] ON [G7ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade7TT_results AS [G7TT] ON [G7TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade8FT_results AS [G8FT] ON [G8FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade8ST_results AS [G8ST] ON [G8ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade8TT_results AS [G8TT] ON [G8TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade9FT_results AS [G9FT] ON [G9FT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade9ST_results AS [G9ST] ON [G9ST].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
LEFT JOIN grade9TT_results AS [G9TT] ON [G9TT].[StudentID]=[Student].[StudentID]
GO
```

And then you can get it this simply from code:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.StudentG1toG9
WHERE [StudentID]=@Id
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. You explained what l was thinking exactly. I don't know what views are so l might have to dig further.

Comment: I don't have a student table. Your query includes one.

Comment: @Nelly What is the parent table for StudentID?

Comment: courseregister table. so i suppose l should swap student with courseregister.

Comment: @Nelly That's why you give your table structures when you ask question so people don't guess what tables you have.  Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Remove `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line of code from your code.

`ExecuteNonQuery()`: Executes a Transact-SQL statement(such as UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE)  against the connection and returns the number of rows affected. But do not returns result sets.